# Application of Divergence theorem to a non-smooth surface

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

**Divergence theorem** that I learnt in analysis:

Let $U \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ be an open, bounded, regular set and let $f : \bar{U} \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ be such that $f$ is bounded and continuous in $U$ and there exist the partial derivatives of $f$ in $\mathbb R^n$ at all $x \in U$ and they are continuous and bounded. Then
$$\int_U \operatorname{Div} f(x) dx = \int_{\partial U} f(x) \cdot \nu d\mathcal H^{n-1},$$

where $\nu$ is normal vector.

If I go back to calc 3, I see many instances where I "exploit" divergence theorem on non-smooth surfaces (such as polygons bounded by the first octant and plane $\{x+y+z = 1\}$). How can I justify divergence theorem on such non-smooth surfaces?

Let $V$ be the non-smooth open set where divergence theorem is applied. Should I take a sequence of regular set $\{U_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ with $U_n \subset V$ such that $\mu(V - U_n) \rightarrow 0$ and take apply divergence theorem on $U_n$. I am assuming the contribution of vector field on $(V - U_n)$ would be small with $\mu(V - U_n) < \epsilon$. However, I am bogged down by the possibility that something strange can happen near the sharp corner of the boundary of $V$. Can anyone justify how I can ignore the "sharp" corner points?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Spivak develops the generalized Stokes's theorem in *Calculus on Manifolds*, integration is really about differential forms on *smooth singular chains*. That is, we're not integrating over manifolds *per se*, but instead integrating over formal integer linear combinations of images of cubes or simplices under smooth maps.

The polygonal/polyhedral regions in multivariable calculus fit immedietaly into this framework.